# Sass - using different variables in @each

Tags: variables, sass, each

I have widths of different planets

```
$mercury-width: 20px;

$venus-width: 30px;

$earth-width: 20px;
```

and their names:

```
`
$planets: mercury, venus, earth;
@each $planet in $planets {
      .#{$planet} {
        width: #{$planet}-width;
      }
    }
```

it doesn't work.

expected result:

```
.mercury {
    width: 20px;
}
```

etc.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```scss
$planets-width: (mercury: 20px, venus: 30px, earth: 20px);
@each $name, $width in $planets-width {
      .#{$name} {
        width: $width;
      }
}
```

Result:

```css
/* line 3, ../scss/test.scss */
.mercury {
  width: 20px;
}

/* line 3, ../scss/test.scss */
.venus {
  width: 30px;
}

/* line 3, ../scss/test.scss */
.earth {
  width: 20px;
}
```

If you want both color and size you can use nested maps:

```scss
$planets-map: (mercury: (width : 20px, color: red), venus: (width : 30px, color : purple), earth:( width: 20px, color: blue));
@each $name, $properties in $planets-map {
      .#{$name} {
        width: map-get($properties, width);
        color: map-get($properties, color);
      }
}
```

Result:

```css
/* line 3, ../scss/test.scss */
.mercury {
  width: 20px;
  color: red;
}

/* line 3, ../scss/test.scss */
.venus {
  width: 30px;
  color: purple;
}

/* line 3, ../scss/test.scss */
.earth {
  width: 20px;
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thank You, but if i have a loop of colors of planets, should i make another array, for example $planets-color: (mercury: red,earth: blue); and after that another @each. it's too more

Comment: @JangBi it was fun to write. Btw you can accept answer ;)